# The Light beam Problem.

Tags: calculus, geometry

I am puzzled with a problem like this.  Suppose you have $N$ lighthouses, each of which has $360/N$ angle of light. Suppose they are arbitrarily allocated on totally flat endless earth (i.e. $R^2$). Can you adjust the lighthouses in a way, that there is no dark place left. You cannot change the places obviously, you can only rotate them.
First it sounds easy, but not really!

Comment: Consider $N=2$.

Comment: Well, it is easy for cases up to 4, then I cannot find a general rule

Comment: Do your lighthouses cast (possibly 1-dimensional) shadows?

Comment: You can ignore the shadows. Otherwise it won't work obviously

Comment: I think where it says "randomly" you mean "arbitarily"?

Comment: Exactly. Thanks, edited.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934293/geometry-question-pertaining-to-4-points-in-the-plane-where-90-degree-projec) asks the same (though really only asks for the $n=4$ case). Also, on Puzzling.SE we have [the 5 lighthouse case](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11486/darkness-in-euclidea). The latter answer links to a [general solution](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/puzzle/solution30.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! The link has the solution to the general case as well!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Geometry question pertaining to $4$ points in the plane where $90$ degree projectors are on each point and we must illuminate the whole plane.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934293/geometry-question-pertaining-to-4-points-in-the-plane-where-90-degree-projec)